# How to Change "capturing voice quality" in delphi firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, voice-recording

I need to change captured voice `quality` programmatically to reduce file size , because of if I use default setting and start capturing voice it will reduce wave file that `1 minute recorded = more than 20 MB` , so I need to change the quality of recording sitting to reduce file size.

Nothing found to tried , the code is worked well , but I need only to decrease recorded file size, by changing the quality of recording voice setting.

```
procedure TForm1.RecordButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Get the default microphone
  try
    Mic := TCaptureDeviceManager.Current.DefaultAudioCaptureDevice;
    if Mic <> nil then
    begin
      // Set the SaveDialog filter to choose only the supported extension
      SaveDialog1.Filter := Mic.FilterString;
      if SaveDialog1.Execute then
      begin
        RecordButton.Enabled := false;
        StopButton.Enabled := true;
        // Gets the name of the file where to save the recorded data
        Mic.FileName := SaveDialog1.FileName;
        Mic.StartCapture;
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      ShowMessage('Audio capturing device not available');
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

```
procedure TForm1.StopButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    if (Mic <> nil) and (Mic.State = TCaptureDeviceState.Capturing) then
    begin
      Mic.StopCapture;
      StopButton.Enabled := false;
      RecordButton.Enabled := true;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What is the file extension of the `FileName` you pass to your Mic? Audio capture device uses this information to determine in which format the audio is stored. WAV format is uncomressed while both WMA and MP3 offers some compression. Mongst the last two mp3 will probably offer better compression (lower file size)

Comment: @SilverWarior The extension of `FileName` is `WAV` , and I changed it to `MP3` but there's no difference between them ,even `WMA` not make a difference in file size , Is there any other solution ?